# BizTalk mapping based on datatype

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I am working on a big schema mapping. One of the mapping's task is normalize a special data type values. For each element with this data value, The Src value need be send to an external assembly for "Normalize".

There're hundreds of this kind of elements in both src and dst schemas. It makes the mapping file extremely large and hard to maintain.

I am wondering if I can use some kind of xslt functorids or even the customized xslt to simply match all the elements with this data type and do the mapping.

For all other elements mapping, simply value copy is enough, but the src and dst have different target schemas.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
I create a simple schema to explain my situation: The schema below.
You can assume there's another schema with same structure but different target namespace. The mapping need find all elements with data type "NM", feed its value to an external assembly. (let's say it is a simple C# string.Reverse())
Then output the value to the same node in dst schema element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://BizTalk_Server_Project1.Schema1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://BizTalk_Server_Project1.Schema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Record1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="R2">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="R3">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="UsedName">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:restriction base="NM" />
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="Age">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:int" />
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="AnotherName">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="NM">
                          <xs:maxLength value="10" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="Gender">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
                    </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Name">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="NM">
                    <xs:maxLength value="10" />
                    <xs:minLength value="1" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="NM">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Could you post a small snippet of the xml please with the special data type.

Comment: Are you actually getting Elements like Record1, Record2, Resord3...Record8762.   If yes, go back to the source and make them change this.  It's not normal Xml.  <Record> should just repeat.

Comment: Thanks. John. Actually the schema is a complex EDI X12 schema. which cannot be changed. The schema above is just a simple sample.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with XSLT 1.0 (but apparently 2.0 can do it?  I'm not really sure, but it doesn't matter because BizTalk and .NET don't support 2.0).

One approach would be to generate a list of nodes (perhaps with their XPaths) from the schema (where the datatype is specified).  You could do this programatically (maybe using XSLT on the XSD file?  parsing it with a .NET class?) or hard code it.  I'd probably opt for hard coding it once you've generated your list.  The list would ideally consist of a set of unique node names or XPaths (maybe with placeholders for the  namespace(s)).  At that point I'd opt for some kind of .NET implementation (using XDocument or XPathNavigator), doing something like this....

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlInput);
foreach (string xPath in ListOfXPaths)
{
    NormalizeData(xdoc.XPathSelectElement(string.Format(xPath, "proper namespace for trading partner here")));
}
...
NormalizeData(XElement el)
{
    el.Value = something else;
}
```

You could do this before or after your map - if the message is coming from a trading partner, do it after, otherwise do it before (you have more control over the namespace(s) that way).

Answer (score 0):

If that is true EDI X12, then the file coming in should give the type of file in the ST01. If you can configure your process to check that field, you could potentially differentiate the file type.